# Is there a way to find out the total memory used by UDP sockets on a system

Tags: sockets, udp, memory-management

By monitoring /proc/net/sockstat or /proc/net/protocols, I am able to find out the total amount of memory used by TCP sockets in the system in realtime:

```
[gpadmin@sdw4 ~]$ cat /proc/net/sockstat
sockets: used 240
TCP: inuse 55 orphan 0 tw 0 alloc 69 mem 2171
UDP: inuse 22 mem 0
RAW: inuse 0
FRAG: inuse 0 memory 0
[gpadmin@sdw4 ~]$ cat /proc/net/sockstat
sockets: used 240
TCP: inuse 55 orphan 0 tw 0 alloc 69 mem 761
UDP: inuse 22 mem 0
RAW: inuse 0
FRAG: inuse 0 memory 0
```

The above metrics show me the memory used by TCP sockets but the UDP socket metrics are marked as 0. Is there a way to find out this information? Any /proc/net files capture this info?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that you have a low traffic?

This is on my machine, receiving 400 UDP packets/sec on 3 ports (there is a 4th UDP stream but I don't use that).

```
# cat /proc/net/sockstat
sockets: used 32
TCP: inuse 6 orphan 0 tw 0 alloc 6 mem 1
UDP: inuse 4 mem 3
```

The same machine, serving those UDP streams to loads of clients on HTTP:

```
#cat /proc/net/sockstat
sockets: used 7232
TCP: inuse 7206 orphan 0 tw 0 alloc 7206 mem 405397
UDP: inuse 4 mem 30
```

The HTTP server is single threaded so I had to set the receive buffer for the UDP sockets quite high to not lose any packets. I've run the test for a while but I've never seen UDP mem go above 50.

Comment: Any idea what "mem" and "alloc" stats for?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I'm completely off base here but I think you need to turn on udp accounting via `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/udp_mem` first before it will collect memory statistics.

Comment: The upd memory throttling is set in this case:  cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/udp_mem 
4651584 6202112 9303168